# Insert text and data into one column via command UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `ps_product_shop` and `ps_product`.

I want update a column in `ps_product_shop` with this command:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_shop` 
SET dm_heureka_product_sk = 'Text' 
AND (SELECT reference from ps_product where id_product = 508) where id_product = 508
```

I get this error:

> #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Text'

How can I insert text + (SELECT reference from ps_product where id_product = 508) ?

Command "Select" take value from ps_product table and from column "reference"

Server mysql: Server version: 5.7.24

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `reference` is unique for `id_product` you can use CONCAT() as such

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET dm_heureka_product_sk = CONCAT('Text', (SELECT reference from ps_product where id_product = 508) where id_product = 508
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a [mysql UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join) :

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop pps
INNER JOIN ps_product pp ON pp.id_product = pps.id_product
SET pps.dm_heureka_product_sk = CONCAT('Text', pps.reference)
WHERE pps.id_product = 508
```

Comment: Thank you very much...it`s works but I have to fix ps.reference to pp.reference :)....